# DNS/Server change causing blank page

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, cache, apache-2.4

We have recently changed servers and hosts of our test|production environment.
Right now we are still testing but our http://test.example.com, is sometimes showing just a blank page to certain users. This has happened on the desktop and mobile environment

We use Amazon Route 53 DNS for DNS, and have recently changed hosting providers from Rackspace to Linode.

The configuration has also changes a little. Nginx now sits in front of apache for static assets. What hasn't changed is using php, mysql, ubuntu.

The strange this is that 99% of the time everything works fine, but in certain instances we have noticed that our testers are seeing a blank page. Page loads, appears to die and the user sees nothing. I did not check the page source, which is next on my list to do, but it has not happened to me.

nginx server config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.testdev.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://testdev.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.bestride.com;
    root /srv/www/example.com/public_html;
    index index.php;

    location ~* ^.+\.(?:js|css|jpe?g|htc|xml|otf|ttf|eot|woff|gif|png|svg|ico|pdf|html|htm)$ {
            access_log off;
            expires 30d;
            #add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
            tcp_nodelay off;
            open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
            open_file_cache_valid 45s;
            open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
            open_file_cache_errors off;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }  

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

}
```

apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin blah@blah.com
    ServerName testdev.example.com
    ServerAlias www.testdev.example.com testdev.example.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined

   <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
       AssignUserId webadmin www-data example
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On

       rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.testdev.example.com [nc]
       rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://testdev.example.com$1 [r=301,nc,qsa]

  </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have heard that browsers cache DNS for easy lookup..blah blah blah. But this is a real concern that users may drop off if they see a blank page.

Clearing the browser cache fixes the issue, but the average user wont do this.

Has anyone experienced a problem like this? Any suggestions?

Thanks
Brian

Comment: "Clearing the browser cache fixes the issue", so you found that it's clearly a browser caching issue when changing DNS settings. Little to do here, change the TTL value in your DNS records to the minimum possible. Ideally you want to have the old server around for a bit while user browsers update to the new DNS values.

Comment: The TTL value in Amazon is set to 60 seconds. The old server is still around, nothing has been shut down. Is this a very common issue?

Comment: No, the blank page is not common, will have to look at the code (esp. JS) and if only happens in subdomain (test.), may be related to cookies

Comment: makes sense that it could be cookies. I have posted my nginx and apache config. I am not doing any caching of apaches responses. is this any help. Can i tell nginx to ignore cookies? Thanks

Comment: Try taking out temporarily the caching in nginx of the static resources block. Also and off-topic, just curious why don't you run everything from nginx instead of having apache at the back? (imho unless there's a particular apache module without equivalent in nginx it's better to just run nginx).

Comment: I do not have much experience with nginx and fastcgi. we will probably move in this direction eventually, but right now other developers need access to this, who may not have a good understanding of nginx. I too am just a beginner but learning more and more everyday. Also can the caching be added back after say a week or two?

Comment: Next time you see a blank page, take a look at the browser's developer console and see what actually occurred.  A blank page could be anything from the server not sending any content to a clientside script failing and not rendering content.

Answer (score 1):

You've completely changed your environment (DNS provider, datacenter provider, etc). I would not look at your nginx configuration because that is too far from the end user, when troubleshooting blank page issues.

Start by being able to replicate the problem and collecting data. Chrome or IE have excellent developer tools (F12) that will allow you to record all records and their results when the issue happens (IE even allows you to record it in a XML file). Then inspect where things break and work from there.

Yes, I have seen it with connections being reset randomly. Once it was an overloaded firewall. Another time was a HTTP server with wrong keep-alive settings. Ad infinitum. You're better off tracking the exact transaction from the end user side and working from there.